# Bean class Vs Collection : which one should i prefer to hold data

Tags: java, collections

I have a `TestDTO` class which holds the 2 input data from user, 
 next step is to fetch the several data from database, lets say i am fetching ten `String` type values from database which requires further to execute the business logic.

I wanted to know the best way to hold the data (in terms of saving memory space and performance)

1. Add 10 more fields in the existing `TestDTO` class and `set` database values at run time
2. Use `java.util.collection (List/Map/..)`
3. Create another DTO/Bean class for 10 `String` values

Answer (score 1):

If you want modularity of your code 3rd point is better, but for simplicity you should use a HashMap, like:

```
HashMap map = new HashMap();

map.put("string1",value);
.....
and so on.
```

This post can be useful for you : https://forums.oracle.com/thread/1153857

Answer (score 1):

If TestDTO and the new values fetched are coming from the same table in the database, then they should be in the same class. Else, the new values should ideally be in another DTO. I do not know the exact scenario that you have, so given these constraints, 2nd option goes out of the window. And options  1 and 3 will depend on your scenario. Always hold values from a single table in one object(preferably).

Comment: Thanks for your time and the valuable suggestion, actually the `TestDTO` is meant for holding input data while i fetch several data from 2 distinct table and i wanted to consolidate in one object for the convenience of further use in business class but i think this should not be done ideally because the data i am fetching via persistence class of 2 distinct table although some columns are common but also want to consolidate all the data in one object(just for the convenience).